# HashMap based nonce for Gnosis-safe MetaTx's?

Tags: gnosis-safe, nonce, meta-transactions

I am using infura's ITX service to handle message delivery, as it is a hard problem.

One thing about ITX is that it doesn't guarantee message order, which is understandable (as that would be hard)....

And as a result, when I have written contracts in the past, to be used with ITX, I have had a HashMap implementation instead of an incremental nonce to avoid metaTX being processed more than once.

Given that the nonce on the Metatx implementation on the gnosis safe is a number increment, do you know of any versions of the safe, that use a hashmap instead of a number increment? Or is there any other advice on how to achieve using a relayer that doesn't guarantee message delivery order to relay MetaTx's to a Gnosis-Safe? Is my best bet to fork the code and change the nonce implementation ? Would love to hear the team's thoughts on this ...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue for this on the Safe contracts repo: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/issues/199

Also something that could be discussed in the Safe forum: https://forum.gnosis-safe.io

Before forking the repository I would rather recommend to write a module with the this functionality.